# Criação de arquivo bat entra no escopo do SOpt?

Tags: debate

Na pergunta **[Escrevendo um arquivo batch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14332/escrevendo-um-arquivo-batch)** o usuário está tendo diculdades para criar um arquivo bat para executar aplicativos. A criação deste arquivo bat pode ser considerada descontextualizada?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

De um modo geral, eu responderia "sim" - pois um batch (arquivo de lotes, script shell, etc) é essencialmente um meio de se executar uma tarefa de forma automatizada. Não há um item específico para esse caso na nossa "poll question", o mais próximo disso que achei é o ["Desenvolvimento de scripts para servidores CRON (entre outros...)"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/658/215) - que seria *on topic*. Talvez fosse o caso de abrir mais um item, e eu já adianto que sou a favor de perguntas desse tipo.

Nesse caso específico, entretanto, trata-se de um batch trivial - sem condicionais, sem loops, sem declaração de variáveis, sem pipes... Apenas uma sequência de comandos, a serem executados sequencialmente. E a autora disse explicitamente que não se trata de uma tarefa de programação/desenvolvimento, somente "alguns atalhos para realizar algumas tarefas". De modo que sou da opinião que deve ser fechada como descontextualizada.

(e de qualquer forma, a pergunta não pode ser respondida no formato atual - a menos que houvesse algum erro de sintaxe ou similar no batch, não há como saber o que está ocorrendo de errado somente com as informações apresentadas)

Comment: TL;DR: shell scripts/batches são on-topic, mas essa pergunta não é bem sobre programação e ainda tem outros problemas, por isso deve ser fechada. Concordo.

Comment: Ainda acho que foi fechada pelo motivo errado. Entendo que a questão é ampla demais, e carece de detalhes apenas. Se a pessoa é ou não experiente, se está fazendo a trabalho ou lição de casa, isso não deveria entrar no julgamento de mérito de on ou off topic. (claro que sou contra lição de casa no sentido de "façam pra mim", mas não é o caso de ser on/off topic, mas sim de baixa qualidade e/ou amplitude demais)

Comment: "Se a pessoa é ou não experiente, se está fazendo a trabalho ou lição de casa" Concordo que isso não deveria importar, mas não foi isso que eu quis dizer com "a autora disse explicitamente que não se trata de uma **tarefa** de programação/desenvolvimento" (ênfase na palavra "tarefa"). Da mesma forma que seria *off-topic* um programador fazendo [perguntas que não são sobre programação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101/215), um não-programador perguntando sobre programação seria ***on-topic***.